# React Native Unable to adjust View width

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, width

I'm trying to create 3 buttons. One of the button will have a long text. I want them to have the same width. For some reason the width doesn't change when I try to change it. [Here how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEMkR.png)

It looks like the width is wrap content. How to solve it and why is it like that?

App.js

```
import React from 'react';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <CustomScrollView >
      <View2>
        <BtnFeature activeOpacity={0.9} onPress={undefined}>
          <FontAwesome name="user" size={40} color='#fff' />
          <PanelText>Text 1</PanelText> 
        </BtnFeature>
        <BtnFeature activeOpacity={0.9} onPress={undefined}>
          <FontAwesome5 name="user" size={40} color='#fff' />
          <PanelText>Very Long Text</PanelText> 
        </BtnFeature>
        <BtnFeature activeOpacity={0.9} onPress={undefined} >
          <FontAwesome5 name="user" size={40} color='#fff' />
          <PanelText>Text 3</PanelText> 
        </BtnFeature>
      </View2>
    </CustomScrollView>
  );
}
```

styles.js

```
export const CustomScrollView = styled.ScrollView`
    margin-top: ${StatusBarHeight - 10}px;
    flex: 1;
    background-color: ${white};
`;

export const PanelText = styled.Text`
    color: ${black}; 
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: ${empty}; 
    text-align: center; 
`;

export const View2 = styled.View`
    background-color: ${gray};
    padding: 15px;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row;
`;

export const BtnFeature = styled.View`
    background-color: ${blizzardBlue};
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 100px;
    width 111px;
    border-radius: 10px;
`;
```

Comment: I don't think anything is wrong in the behaviour. space-between won't do the trick(it's for spacing you know). You have to manually assign the space equally like we do in grid ```grid-auto-columns: minmax(0, 1fr);
grid-auto-flow: column;```.

Comment: @ShobhitTewari I'm not actually making a grid. `GridView` is jus a normal `View`. I don't quite understand what you mean. I want the buttons to be evenly  spaced.  That's why I used `justify-content: space-between;`

Comment: How about giving them 33% width each. Or make it a gridview(makes life easier). Your code is behaving as expected there is nothing in the code that can split 3 equal columns. You have to add more code.

Comment: If you give each of the buttons flex: 1, they will take up the same space